# Can T4 templates be used to generate manual Dispose()-code from "using" statements?

Tags: c#, code-generation, t4, idisposable, using

I am using this [pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515486/usingidisposable-obj-new-in-c-sharp-to-write-code-blocks-in-stream-e-g) that abuses the usage of IDisposable to properly format the output of an xml:

```
public class XmlDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private TextWriter xml;
    private string tag;
    public XmlDisposable(TextWriter xml, string tag)
    {
        this.xml = xml;
        this.tag = tag;
        xml.Write("<" + tag + ">");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        xml.WriteLine("</" + tag + ">");
    }
}

public static XmlDisposable Note(this TextWriter xml)
{
    return new XmlDisposable(xml, "note");
}

public static XmlDisposable Body(this TextWriter xml)
{
    return new XmlDisposable(xml, "body");
}
```

Usage:

```
public void WriteNote(TextWriter xml, string bodyText)
{
    using (xml.Note())
    {
        using (xml.Body())
        {
            xml.Write(bodyText);
        }
    }
}
```

This works because the using will be replaced by the compiler with a "try ... finally" statement.

My question is the following:
Could I use a T4 template to modify the source files such that each block of "using (xml...())" will be replaced with something like the following:

```
 var xml = new XmlDisposable(xmlWriter, tagName);
 ...
 (xml as IDisposable).Dispose();
```

I know that it might not be a good idea to do it because of the additional overhead to maintain the template as well as to produce the code, but I am just curious if it could be done.

Thank you!

Comment: T4 cannot modify files.  Roslyn could help you.

Comment: Also, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Finally, don't build XML by hand; it's a recipe for disaster.  Use `XDocument` or `XmlWriter`.

Comment: Do you have any good reason to generate XML manually? Off the top of my head, I can think of no less than 4 built-in ways to generate XML in .NET: XmlWriter, XmlDocument, XDocument (Linq to XML), and XML serialization.

Comment: @SLaks: Ok, generate a new file like the existing one but with the mentioned changes. And for no particular reason, as I said, I am just curios.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: I absolutely agree that there are much better ways to generate an XML doc.

Comment: T4 won't help you parse existing code either.